# How to properly do circular type definitions in C++?

Tags: c++, recursion

I am trying to implement an undirected graph storing neighbours in a linked list. Because be will be removing edges later, I also need to store an iterator to the opposite edge to allow for synchronised removal.

This is where the circularity comes in. Basically, i am trying to do something like:

```
typedef std::list<Edge> Node;
typedef std::pair<Node*,Node::iterator> Edge;
```

[Obviously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Incomplete_types) this won’t work. Can i somehow abuse inheritance to break out of the loop? Will this one universally work on all compilers?

```
struct Edge;
typedef std::list<Edge> Node;
struct Edge:public std::pair<Node*,Node::iterator>{using pair::pair;};
```

Also, what’s the idiomatic C++ way to do this?

Comment: A forward declaration, like you have done, is the correct way.

Comment: That should work on all compilers. However, I question the base type of `Edge`. It's not clear from your question why you need that.

Comment: @RSahu For example, an `1→2` edge in the `1` node needs to contain a pointer to the `2` node (to know where we go) and an iterator pointing to the `2→1` edge (to remove it too when we get removed)

Comment: @RSahu I don’t know how to do it without inheritance. Edge needs to know that Node is a list.

Comment: @kinokijuf - you just want containment: the struct Edge needs to _contain_ member fields for the Node it is connecting to and the iterator (in your design).  It will know that the Node is a list of Edge because it has seen the typedef of it.  (Consider the difference between _is a_ and _has a_ ... the classic object-oriented design dichotomy.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to forward declare *something* to have circular referencing (Circular inclusion is still impossible)

A more idiomatic way would to give the members of `Edge` better names than `first` and `second`.

```
struct Edge
{
    Node * destination;
    Node::iterator dual;
};
```